# Why do I get "The action 'index' could not be found for PeopleController"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm getting started with Ruby on Rails and am following an online tutorial.  The tutorial had me modify my routes.rb file by adding the following line:

```
resources :people
```

I also typed in `rails generate controller People` previously.  controllers/people_controllers.rb looks like this:

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
end
```

Everything looks good to me.  However, `http://0.0.0.0:3000/people` gives me an error:

```
Unknown action
The action 'index' could not be found for PeopleController
```

I don't think I should need to do this, but when I add:

```
def index
end
```

to my controller, and refresh the page, I get the following error instead:

```
 Template is missing

Missing template people/index, application/index with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder], :locale=>[:en, :en], :formats=>[:html]}. Searched in: * "/Users/myuser/projects/project_manager/app/views"
```

I'm using the newest version of Ruby, and Rails v3. Everything was installed today.  What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've created the controller but not defined the view for it. Add a file called `index.html.erb` in directory `app/views/people`.

Alternatively you can re-run the controller generator to generate the index view:

```
rails g controller People index
```

Also it is a good idea to read the Rails Guides. For your understanding of views and rendering [read this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-by-default-convention-over-configuration-in-action).

Comment: Or `def index ; render text: 'ohai'; end` if you want a quick test without the hassle of creating a separate view file.

Comment: and what if I don't have and I don't want to have an "index" view?

Answer (score 1):

Just to help complete this thread, another potential cause of this error is when you forget that at some point during development you changed the signature of the associated controller method as though it would be used internally by adding, for example, a formal parameter list, e.g. you changed

> def my_controller_method

to

> def my_controller_method(my_parameter)

when you should instead have been using the former signature and catching the parameters from the view using, e.g.

> params[:my_parameter]

The latter signature won't match up with the one the view is sending which will generate this error.

---

Yet another cause is when you forgot that you made the target method private.  Move it to the public section of your controller to make it visible to the view (and to other controllers).

Answer (score -3):

instead of:

```
resources :people
```

use

```
resources :peoples
```

Remember, the rails compiler always look for plurality of controller class